# how to show inverse of M-by-N data matrix using singular value decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, pseudoinverse, inverse-problems

The question is from the exercise questions from the EE4595 course being taught in TUDelft. The question is as follows...

[image]

So far my attempted solution is like the following.

The discretised data equation is given by $d=G_S\cdot q$ where $G_S$ is M-by-N data matrix and $q$ is N-by-1 source vector. To arrive at $q$ we need to invert $G_S$ and since $G_S$ is non-square it is non-invertible therefore, I thought the closest we get to the solution by using pseudo inverse resulting in $q=G_S^{\dagger}d$. However, the question apparently asks us to use singular value decomposition to show this process and this is where I got stuck. Any help to solve this question would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds to me like the question is simply asking you to show that the matrix $G_S^\dagger$ satisfies the Moore-Penrose conditions. For example, note that
$$
G_S [V_RS_R^{-1}U_R^H]G_S = \\
[U_R S_R V_R^H] [V_RS_R^{-1}U_R^H] [U_R S_R V_R^H] =\\
U_R S_R [V_R^H V_R] S_R^{-1} [U_R^HU_R]S_R V_R^H =\\
U_R [S_R  S_R^{-1} S_R] V_R^H =\\
U_RS_RV_R^H = G_S,
$$
which means that $G_S^\dagger$ (as given by the SVD formula) satisfies the first condition. Because of what the question has told you, if we can do this for all 4 conditions, then we can deduce that $G_S^\dagger$ is the MP inverse.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks for your comment, I think you are right.  Maybe it is obvious but I couldn't understand how $V_R^H V_R$ and $U_R^HU_R$ disappeared on the 3rd line do they result in an identity matrix?

Comment: Yes; $V_R^HV_R$ is an identity matrix because the columns of $V_R$ are orthonormal